# Out of range exception on basic_string::replace, while in range, as proven by debugging output of the same parameters

Tags: c++, string, replace, iterator, range

I'm working on some code to translate between programming languages, but I'm getting an out of range exception on a string.replace(), except that my iterators are in range, and it only occurs occasionally.  I threw in some debugging output to pinpoint exactly when it fails, which seems to be whenever it feels like it, but always in the same place.  It works a few times, then fails.  Here's a code snippet, so you can see where the iterators and debugging lines are.

```
            while (refactor_required){

            cout << "\nPerforming refactoring on equation: " << current_eq << current_assign << endl;
            cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
            for (std::string::iterator itr1=current_eq.begin(); itr1<(current_eq.end()); itr1++)
            {
                if (*itr1=='~'&&*(itr1+1)=='('){
                    std::string::iterator itr2=(extract_subexp_end(&current_eq,(itr1+2),0));
                    current_subexp=(string((itr1+2),(itr2-1)));
                    cout.rdbuf((*logfile).rdbuf());
                    cout << "\nNegating subexpression : " << current_subexp << endl;
                    cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
                    negation_refactor(&current_subexp);
                    cout.rdbuf((*logfile).rdbuf());
                    cout << "\nNegated subexpression : " << current_subexp << endl;
                    cout << "About to replace " <<string(itr1,itr2)<< " wif " << "("+current_subexp+")"<< endl;
                    current_eq.replace(itr1,itr2,"("+current_subexp+")");
                    cout << "Replaced " << endl;
                    cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
                    itr1=extract_subexp_end(&current_eq,(itr1+1),0); //Advance to end of newly inserted text
                }

            }

            current_split=split_on_delimiters(&current_eq);
```

Below is the output from the log, you can see it succeeds several times:

```
Negating subexpression : WA38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.3

Negated subexpression : ~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3
About to replace ~(WA38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.3) wif (~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3)
Replaced 

Negating subexpression : WB38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.6

Negated subexpression : ~WB38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.6
About to replace ~(WB38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.6) wif (~WB38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.6)
Replaced 

Negating subexpression : WA38HLOR^~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2

Negated subexpression : ~WA38HLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.2+WA38HLOR*~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2
About to replace ~(WA38HLOR^~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2) wif (~WA38HLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.2+WA38HLOR*~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2)
Replaced 

Negating subexpression : ~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3

Negated subexpression : WA38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.3
About to replace ~(~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3) wif (WA38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.3)
```

The last entry before the core dump is in the above log, "About to replace".  Here's the output from the terminal window:

```
Performing refactoring on equation: (WA38HLOR^~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2)^~(WA38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.3)*~(WB38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.6)*(WC38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.9)*W38GEG.ENABLED=WA38LOP
Negated expression: WA38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.3 into: ~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3
Negated expression: WB38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.6 into: ~WB38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.6

Refactored to: (~(WA38HLOR^~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2)*(~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3)+~(~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3)*WA38HLOR^~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2)*~WB38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.6*WC38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.9*W38GEG.ENABLED

Performing refactoring on equation: (~(WA38HLOR^~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2)*(~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3)+~(~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3)*WA38HLOR^~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2)*~WB38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.6*WC38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.9*W38GEG.ENABLED=WA38LOP
Negated expression: WA38HLOR^~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2 into: ~WA38HLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.2+WA38HLOR*~W38GEG.ACTIVE.2
Negated expression: ~WA38RLOR*W38GEG.ACTIVE.3 into: WA38RLOR+~W38GEG.ACTIVE.3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::replace: __pos (which is 18446744073709551018) > this->size() (which is 205)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm kind of at a loss here.  I've tried first erasing that section of the string, then inserting the text where I like, but the result is the same.  The text returned by using string(itr1,itr2) on cout shows that they are 100% in the right place, haven't been modified or gone out of scope, but the replace line just fails, and only does so sporadically.

Comment: I would be concerned about iterator invalidation. For example, if you replace a short string with a longer one the string might have to reallocate, and all iterators would be invalidated. You also use `itr1+2`in some places. Are you sure that `itr1` isn't close the `end()` at that point?

Comment: Second question first:  Yes, I've already significantly manipulated and performed validation on the original code by this point in the program, so if I have a negation and a left parentheses, it would have been rejected long ago if nothing followed.  As for the first part, is this a case of the iterator itself being "automatically" invalidated between the cout line and the line directly below?  If that's a thing the language does, it could be it.  I mostly treat them like pointers with a "don't be stupid" approach- itr1 here will point to the start of my text but itr2 is useless after replace

Comment: Yes, iterators and pointers are similar. What can happen here is that if the string creates a larger buffer, all existing iterators will "point" into the old, now deleted, buffer. Much like a dangling pointer.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Does that mean replace is only safe to use when the string is shorter?  I suppose I could instead do       current_eq=string(current_eq.begin(),itr1)+"("+current_subexp+")"+string(itr2,current_eq.end());     but that seemed needlessly complicated and I'll still need a couple more lines to figure out where to reset itr1 to.

Comment: `replace` as such is safe to use. What might *not* be safe is to continue using pointers or iterators into a string that has changed its size.

Comment: It seems that the iterators change during the replace, so calling 'replace' with iterators throws the error, because I've demonstrated right before the error that the iterators are in the correct place, performed no additional actions with the string or the iterators, then called replace with them.  Is it that replace breaks iterators before it uses them, so while it accepts iterators, you can't trust it to actually use them?  That's the part I can't comprehend.

Comment: `itr1+2` is out of bounds. Therefore *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Galik 'itr1+2' shouldn't be out of bounds.  Are you quite sure you're reading it correctly?  The issue occurred at the line containing the "replace," immediately after I demonstrated with the "About to replace" output that the iterators were valid and in bounds.

Comment: I don't see how `itr1+2` can be in bounds when `iter1 == (end - 1)` because that would make `(itr1+2) == end + 1`. Strings protect `*end` because of the null terminator but `*(end + 1) has to be out of bounds by my reconning.

Comment: Because at this location in the program, I'm well past the point of accepting external input, have confirmed it's valid Boolean, regenerated the logic into completely different syntax and reconfirmed it's valid Boolean logic, so it's 100% safe to assume that (*itr1=='~'&&*(itr1+1)=='(') will never occur at the end of a string.  It's impractical to add thousands of checks for things that can never happen and are already checked for.  Could I save a couple checks of characters against '~' by adjusting bounds?  Probably.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more verbose, but functional, version of my original code is

```
int itr_stored;
for (std::string::iterator itr1=current_eq.begin(); itr1<(current_eq.end()); itr1++)
{
    if (*itr1=='~'&&*(itr1+1)=='('){
        std::string::iterator itr2=(extract_subexp_end(&current_eq,(itr1+2),0));
        current_subexp=(string((itr1+2),(itr2-1)));
        current_sub_left=string(current_eq.begin(),itr1);
        current_sub_right=string(itr2,current_eq.end());
        negation_refactor(&current_subexp);
        current_eq=current_sub_left+"("+current_subexp+")";
        itr_stored=current_eq.length();
        current_eq.append(current_sub_right);
        itr1=(current_eq.begin()+itr_stored);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a call to `current_eq.replace`, any iterators into `current_eq` may be invalidated.  This includes `itr1`.  You continue to use it, resulting in Undefined Behavior.  It will be referring to freed (unallocated) memory, and likely will (at least initially) still contain the previous contents of `current_eq`.  Later, when you call a second `replace` on that same string, the iterator into the string is bad, resulting in this error.

A possible fix to this problem is to use indexing (instead of iterators), or to recalculate the position of the iterator based on an index after the replace call.

Comment: Thank you.  When you say "may be invalidated," does that mean what it sounds like, that it only happens sometimes?  Surely there's a way to determine whether they will be programmatically?  I have quite a few iterators that replace substrings with shorter strings in this program, for example 'AND'->'+', do those all need to be converted to indexing as well?

Comment: @MGreene It's what the standard says "may be invalidated".  In practical terms that _probably_ means if the string memory needs to be reallocated, but you can't count on it, and different implementations of the library may have different behaviors.  There's nothing that requires the new string to reuse memory from the old one.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'll just go ahead and convert them all then.  Though I haven't encountered issues with them, I will be compiling this in Visual Studio for Win32 targets at some point, and I'm using GCC on Linux64 for my testing.